# What's the meaning of this syntax ?> <?php

Tags: php

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
{
?> // why this
 <tr>
  <td> <?php echo $i; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo "tên sách $i"; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo "noi dung sach $i";?></td>
 </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

So that is the scenario I'm looking to understand. Thanks

Comment: That script is mixing HTML and PHP ... Anything outside the PHP tags will be rendered as HTML ...

Comment: I suggest you read through http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Comment: Just to get your feet wet: with '<?' or '<?php' you'll enter into PHP code; with '?>' you'll exit from PHP code and reenter in (for example) HTML mode. Start with PHP.NET examples and manuals, and write your first hello world script.

Answer (score 5):

The `<?php` opens a php script sequence so it is saying that inside this is php code.  `?>` closes that sequence and says that I am not longer using php code.

In your case the php opens up and starts a for loop.  Inside of the for loop a table is made but it is done using html not php.  Then in each table piece, php is being used to echo (write something to the screen) some content into the table.  Then finally at the end the php for loop must be finished with a closed bracket.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of that syntax, is essentially telling the server to stop processing PHP. What follows in the page, is HTML code. That is `<?php` tells the server *process this as PHP script* and the `?>` says *stop processing PHP script*.

Normally, you'll not see HTML outputted in this manner, but instead using PHP's `echo` to write the HTML

```
<?php
 for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
 {
 echo "
 <tr>
  <td>{$i}</td>
  <td>\"tên sách {$i}\"</td>
  <td>\"noi dung sach {$i}\"</td>
 </tr>
 ";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't agree that you normally don't see php tags mixed with HTML code. For example, any drupal theme I know use HTML/PHP presentation code mixed.

Comment: @dAm2K Even my implementation above, I wouldn't consider 'great'. Good coding practices will separate the logic code from the display code. [Display from logic](http://tebros.com/2010/02/separate-display-from-logic/)

Comment: Sure, in fact I wrote PHP presentation code. Any template has presentation logic, some template engine make use of PHP directly (ptemplate, for ex), other implements their own (smarty, for ex).

Answer (score 0):

`?>` is the end tag of PHP much like `</td>` is an end tag of a table cell.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP parser lets you enable and disable parsing by including the PHP start and end tags `<?php` and `?>` in your document. These two samples have the same output:

```
One
-------------------
echo '<td>' . $foo . '</td>';

Two
-------------------
?>
<td><?php echo $foo; ?></td>
<?php
```

As far as which is easier to read, well, that's a matter of preference I suppose.

See also: the [shortcut tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php#example-66) `<?=` for echoing a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can come in and out of php execution any time you like. If text is not between php tags, it will be output rather than executed.

```
<?php // start executing
if($test){ ?> <!-- start a php if statement -->
<p>This will only be output if the php test is true</p>
<?php } ?> <!-- don't forget to close the if statement -->
<p>This will always be output</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows you to min PHP code and HTML markup in the same file, so it needs a way to tell them apart.

If you don't enclose your PHP code between `<?php` and `?>`, it won't be processed, and will be output as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should read a minimum of documentation before start a project (and ask basic questions).

First part (l.1 to 4) is PHP code, here you start a for loop.
Second part (l.5 to 9) is HTML code, which is include in the loop.
Third and last part is here to close the loop.

You can do the same with :

```
<?php
   for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
      echo "<td>tên sách".$i."</td>";
      echo "<td>noi dung sach".$i."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to embed the HTML code without having to use the php print or echo function.  using 
    ?>

Another way to get at the same result would be this:
    ";
        echo "  $i ";
        echo "  tên sách $i ";
        echo "  noi dung sach $i ";
        echo "";
    }
    ?>